# Create Cased Line Symbology for Feature Service in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online

I'm trying to render a line feature service with a cased symbol.  For those of you unaware, a cased symbol is essentially like drawing an outline around the line.  It creates a very nice visualization.  My current workaround is to create a copy of the feature service and draw the copied layer slightly larger.  This creates the effect but now I have two layers in my contents pane and this is undesirable.  I'm surprised by ESRI's shortcomings in regards to the rendering options they provide in ArcGIS Online.  From what I've seen it looks like they provide very few options.

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Online is underdeveloped in general. I think your best option would be adding a small [buffer layer](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/create-buffers.htm) around your polylines and choose whatever colour is most visually appealing for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response Daniel.  I'm essentially doing that with the second layer.  I'd be okay with this approach if there were a way to group the layers so they turn on and off together.  ESRI has come a long ways with its Web App builder but I still find that you have to make compromises when using ArcGIS Online as a hosting platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability (licenses, servers, etc) you can publish a map and/or feature service from desktop (ArcMap or Pro) and casing symbology will come through. Creating that symbology style from within ArcGIS Online is not available thus far.

Comment: Right, I should have specified that  I'm rendering the layer with graduated symbols.  I tried publishing from Pro and got a message that the symbology will be downgraded.